# Java - Compute method in instantiable seemingly bypassed when run

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to run the compute method in the instantiable class and it's not working. The app class seemingly just bypasses it and I seriously cannot figure out why.
The result is: "The average for each week is:[]"

**App class:**

```
    package rainfall;

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    //import java.util.Arrays;

    public class RainfallApp {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rainfall r = new Rainfall();

        r.compute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, r.getResult());

    }
}
```

**Instantiable class:**

```
    package rainfall;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Rainfall {
private int[][] rain = new int[4][7];
private int[] average = new int[4]; 
private int[] sum = new int[4];

public Rainfall(){
    rain = new int[][]{};
    average = new int[]{};
    sum = new int[]{};
}

public void compute(){
    for (int i= 0; i < rain.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < rain[0].length; j++) {
            rain[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter value"));

            sum[i] = rain[i][j] + sum[i];
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum));

        }

        average[i] = sum[i] / rain[i].length;

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't even get the System.out.println... to work, whether it's placed in the for i loop or the for j loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to start out by asking whether you even used the debugger or not, and inspected the value of your variables.

From what I can see by the code example you provided I can clearly see why none of your for loops is even running. To put it simple, you are trying to run loops on empty arrays.

The reason that your arrays are empty is because of your constructor as seen in the code below:

```
public class Rainfall {
    private int[][] rain = new int[4][7];
    private int[] average = new int[4]; 
    private int[] sum = new int[4];

    public Rainfall(){
        rain = new int[][]{};
        average = new int[]{};
        sum = new int[]{};
    }
}
```

In the example provided your constructor is overwriting the values already assigned to your fields with empty arrays. You need to decide whether you want to assign values to your fields directly (not recommended) or in your constructor (recommended) and not both. Bellow is the two options explained above:

Directly assigning values: (Bad practice)

```
public class Rainfall {
    private int[][] rain = new int[4][7];
    private int[] average = new int[4]; 
    private int[] sum = new int[4];

    public Rainfall(){
    }
}
```

Assigning values to your fields in your constructor:

```
public class Rainfall {
    private int[][] rain;
    private int[] average; 
    private int[] sum;

    public Rainfall(){
        rain = new int[4][7];
        average = new int[4]; 
        sum = new int[4];
    }
}
```

Comment: I had ran the debugger, with no errors. Your above example GIVES me errors, I did try your way :/

Comment: I'm going to try uninstalling and reinstalling NetBeans, maybe that's where I'm going wrong.

Comment: let me do a quick check, I apologize if I may have mistyped something.

Comment: I installed in on my personal computer as I was using it on my college virtual machine. Works well on my personal computer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I too had no issues running the code. Also if the answer I provided helped you fix your issue I would kindly ask that you mark this as the answer to your question :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is: read again about the syntax around arrays.

The code within your constructor:

```
public Rainfall(){
 rain = new int[][]{};
 average = new int[]{};
 sum = new int[]{};
```

Simply doesn't make any sense. You see, you are **already** initializing all three arrays at their declaration. You create perfectly valid arrays, to then overwrite in a constructor ... that wouldnt be required in the first place.

Comment: Your answer is not very constructive. You are only pointing fingers in a general direction, lacking a proper explanation as to what the actual problem is and why it happens

Comment: Well, how to I fix it? What do I do? I have searched extensively before asking my question and can't find out how to declare the 2D arrays in the default constructor.